# FullCalendar - How to remove the Hours and only have the Weekdays?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I've been looking into the [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) with the [Scheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler) plugin and i can't figure out how to remove the hours from the calendar. I'm only interested in only having the names of the weekdays, is it possible to do that?

[Here is how the Calendar looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Wp0.jpg)

Comment: I think you just need to make one slot span a whole day. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration e.g. `slotDuration: { days:1 }`

Comment: @ADyson I was fooling with the `slotDuration` like you said and it worked! I just had to give it a 24 hour duration like this: `slotDuration: '24:00:00'`. I also change some the values of `minTime: "00:00:00"` and `maxTime: "24:00:00"` just to make sure it worked, but it doesn't seem relevant. If you place your comment as an answer i will accept it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to make one slot span a whole day.

e.g.

```
slotDuration: { days:1 }
```

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to give it a 24 hour duration like this: `slotDuration: '24:00:00'`. I also change some the values of `minTime: "00:00:00"` and `maxTime: "24:00:00"` just to make sure it worked, but it doesn't seem relevant.

```
    minTime: "00:00:00",
    maxTime: "24:00:00",
    slotDuration: '24:00:00', 
    nowIndicator: false,
```